# Error while publishing worker role in VS 2013: There was an error reflecting type 'Microsoft.Cct.AzureDiagnostics.ObjectModel.PublicConfig'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-worker-roles

I am getting error while publishing worker role from Visual Studio 2013 with update 5. When i select worker role project and click on publish, it is showing me below error on pop up window and i am not able to move ahead:

**There was an error reflecting type 'Microsoft.Cct.AzureDiagnostics.ObjectModel.PublicConfig'.**

Any help related this is appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ecf78452-3b70-45a3-a7be-dec0c53e658a/reflection-error-for-type-39microsoftcctazurediagnosticsobjectmodelpublicconfig39?forum=windowsazuredevelopment):

1. In your Azure project, edit any `diagnostics.wadcfgx` files in a text editor, and set `<IsEnabled>false</IsEnabled>` (near the bottom)
2. Right click project > Publish, untick `Send diagnostics data to Application Insights`, hit Next

I had upgraded from Azure SDK 2.3 to 2.9.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue after upgrading Azure Tools from 2.6 to 2.9 - I solved it by going into *Programs and Features* and uninstalling all items that started with "Microsoft Azure" and had a 2.6 version number in the name, leaving only the 2.9 behind (all with Visual Studio 2013 closed). Then I restarted Visual Studio 2013 and it magically started working properly!

Answer (score 1):

I.ve installed the Azure SDK 2.7 (the features for VS2013), restarted the VS2013 and it worked again, you can download the SDK items manually at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178